FedCM get() rejects with AbortError: signal is aborted without reason
I have "sign in with google' functionality on website, its implemented using javascript. It was working fine, but now it started to throw "client:50 [GSI_LOGGER]: FedCM get() rejects with AbortError: signal is aborted without reason" when we fire google.accounts.id.prompt(). And this issue is on Chrome., its working on other browsers. I lready checked cooling down period.
Do anybody know solution?
My code is
google.accounts.id.initialize({
client_id: '########',
callback: handleCredentialResponse,
use_fedcm_for_prompt: true
});
google.accounts.id.prompt();

Same issue. For a temporary solution you can force gsi no use FedCM
google.accounts.id.initialize({
  ...
  use_fedcm_for_prompt: false // yes, explicitly passing false prevents the use of FedCM
})


setting use_fedcm_for_prompt: false as well dont work on chrome.
it dont open any poup prompt.

Same issue too. We found out that google.accounts.id.prompt may skipped when tap_outside. So we trigger google.accounts.id.prompt again when tap_outside happened.
google.accounts.id.prompt((notification) => {
  if (notification.getSkippedReason() === 'tap_outside') {
    google.accounts.id.prompt();
  }
});

